# Add Content Security Policy in Nginx

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am adding Content Security Policy in Nginx for my website as:

example:

add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://m.youtube.com https://www.youtube.com; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self' https://a23-abc-11.somecdn.com;";

Some media assets are being downloaded from CDN as I have specified in "media-src". But the URLs keep on changing like:

https://34r-qw2d.abc-11.somecdn.com

https://g67-xyv-1.somecdn.com

How to handle this. I tried adding wildcard in CSP like:

```
https://*.*.*.somecdn.com
```

This does not work.

Please advise how to handle this scenario.

Comment: https://content-security-policy.com/

Did you tried `*.somecdn.com` without `https://` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `https://*.*.*.somecdn.com` syntax is wrong, the [* in CSP](https://csplite.com/csp89/) is not acts the same as [Wildcard character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) in computing.

Just use `https://*.somecdn.com` to allow any subdomains.